# Specify the version to be upgraded

Tags: 14.04, 16.04, upgrade

I want to know if there is any way to specify the version I want to upgrade to. I mean, I have a server with 14.04 and I want to update to 16.04 and only this version.

Is there any way to tell Ubuntu to upgrade to this specific version and not allow to install any other (15.XX, 17.XX, 18.04 LTS...)

Thanks!

Comment: `do-release-upgrade` in 14.04 LTS should go to 16.04 LTS right now.  18.04 LTS is not due out for another couple of weeks, so you should be fine.

Comment: You should [read this thread](https://askubuntu.com/questions/91815/how-to-install-software-or-upgrade-from-an-old-unsupported-release); it explains everything you've asked about.

Comment: Seamus that is not a good link. It's for unsupported releases. At least that is how it looks on my phone.

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix Ah, I see.  Makes sense.  My other comment is gone.  =)

Comment: @Terrance My comments are ashes too and an answer arose like a phoenix :)

Answer (score 1):

From: [How to Update a Ubuntu LTS release to the next LTS Version (release upgrade)](https://www.howtoforge.com/tutorial/ubuntu-lts-update-dist-upgrade/)

```
apt-get update
apt-get install update-manager-core
```

Edit `/etc/update-manager/release-upgrades` and ensure the last line reads:

```
Prompt=lts
```

Then run:

```
do-release-upgrade -d
```

### Note: `-d` option only until 18.04.1 comes out!

Answer (score 0):

In `Software & Updates`. Go to `Updates` Tab. In option `Notify me a New Ubuntu Version`, You need to select For `long-term support version`. It will identify next available LTS automatically and prompt you for upgrade.
Note that it LTS upgrade option will be prompt once point release is released i.e for Ubuntu 18.04 Point release is Ubuntu 18.04.1.